# Dynamically Get Response from Form

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms, dynamic

Okay guys, ive been at this for a few hours now, not sure where to even begin or start, so ill start with this.  I've used samples from all over but just can't seem to tailor them to my needs.

i have a start page, we'll call this "Portal.php"  Basically what I'm trying to do is implement "dynamicAddUser.php" into the page by getting it's contents when an image button appears, it comes up underneath it.  It needs to create this form:

```
<form id="addUser" method="POST">
<label>Username <input name="user" /></label><br/>
<label>Password <input name="pass" type="password"/>
</label>
<button name="submit">Add User</button></form>
```

Basically I need it to submit the form to "response.php" and get the output of it dynamically without changing the page.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

edit:

```
<html>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head> <meta charset="UTF-8"> 

<style media="print">
#goBack,#printRow {
   display:none;
}
</style>

</head>
<body id="body" class="body">

<form id="addUser" method="POST">
    <label>Username <input name="user" /></label><br/>
    <label>Password <input name="pass" type="password"/></label>
    <button id="createUser" name="submit">Add User</button>
</form>

<div id="container" class="container">
div contents here
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $('#addUser').on('submit', function(){
    var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'response.php',
        data: postData,
        type: "POST"
    }).done(function(html_response){
        // Assuming you are sending and html from php using
        // echo instead of json_encode().
        // You can use body instead of #container. It depends on what you return
        $('#container').html('ajax done successfully');
    });
});     
</script>
</meta>
</body>
</html>
```

Ive finally got it doing what I need to be doing, there's some issue with Firefox not working with the requests of the button (pulled some hair out with that.)
But alas!  One step closer, right now I'm having trouble just writing the response out :/  I've tried everything I can think of on this one, thanks again!

Comment: The only way is by using AJAX.
Please read the guide http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/

Comment: Are you simple trying to submit a POST form and get the response via ajax?

Comment: That is what I'm trying to do!

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use AJAX with php. Let's assume you will use jQuery.

response.php

```
$user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];

// Save your user
$data = ['saved' => true, 'user' => $user, 'message' => 'You are now registered'];
// Or if you are using PHP 5.3 or under
$data = array('saved' => true, 'user' => $user, 'message' => 'You are now registered');
return json_encode($data);
```

portal.php

```
...
<form id="addUser" method="POST">
    <label>Username <input name="user" /></label><br/>
    <label>Password <input name="pass" type="password"/></label>
    <button id="createUser" name="submit">Add User</button>
</form>
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#addUser').on('submit', function(){
    var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'response.php',
            data: postData,
            type: "POST"
        }).done(function(data){
            // Now you can use the data as you like with jQuery
            $('.message').addClass('success').html(data.message);
            $('#user').html(data.user.name); // Or whatever
        });
    });
</script>
```

You can also send an html partial to replace a whole part of the page:

```
$('#addUser').on('submit', function(){
    var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'response.php',
        data: postData,
        type: "POST"
    }).done(function(html_response){
        // Assuming you are sending and html from php using
        // echo instead of json_encode().
        // You can use body instead of #container. It depends on what you return
        $('#container').html(html_response);
    });
});
```

Comment: First of all I want to say thank you so much, whatever I was doing earlier when attempting this just wasn't working, so this is greatly appreciated!  It seems like it's going to work but i keep getting an error on this line
   Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')'

Comment: First of all I want to say thank you so much, whatever I was doing earlier when attempting this just wasn't working, so this is greatly appreciated!  It seems like it's going to work but i keep getting an error on this line

return json_encode(['saved' => true, 'user' => $user, 'message' => 'You are now registered']);

   Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')'

I've done everything I can think of with it to even re-writing it as a function.  This "response" page is the one that also handles the functionality for adding the user to the db, am i going about this wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: What version of php you are using? If it's under 5.4, the array cannot be defined using square braces `[]` but `array()` instead. I edited the answer. Take a look again.

Answer (score 0):

Form.html

```
<form id="addUser" method="POST">
<label>Username <input class='username' name="user" /></label><br/>
<label>Password <input class='password' name="pass" type="password"/>
</label>
<button id='register' onclick='submitForm()' name="submit">Add User</button>
</form>
<div class='result'></div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
function submitForm() {
 var username = $.trim($('.username').val());
 var password = $.trim($('.password').val());
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "response.php",
    data: "username="+username+"&password="+password, 
    cache: false,
    success: function(html) {
            $('.result').html(html).fadeIn('fast');
    }
 });
}
</script>
```

response.php

```
<?php
 echo $username = $_POST['username'].'<br/>';
 echo $password = $_POST['password'];
?>
```

You can also serialize data from the form in ajax

Comment: This is awesome, thank you so much for giving me something extra to work with!  My problem now is that response.php doesn't seem to be executing any code, there isn't any validation at that point except to check that the user and pass data submitted isn't null with 
     if(isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['pass']))
Everything after that is golden when i submit the test form from another page, just not sure what's going on in the middle?